# Hiding and Expanding Menus

Tags: javascript

I've created code for a menu system that can show / hide menus and submenus. Now I wonder if the structure of the code is good enough or if you find something that can be done better?

```
var initExpanders = function () {
    "use strict";

    function lsTest(){
        var test = 'localstoragetest';
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(test, test);
            localStorage.removeItem(test);
            return true;
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    var IS_OPEN = 'open',
        localStorageisAvailable = lsTest();

    /**
     * Add the small arrows indicating an expander.
     *
     * @returns {string} to be inserted in document.
     */
    function expandButton() {
        return '<span class="indicator icon-down-open"></span>' +
            '<span class="indicator icon-up-open"></span>';
    }

    /**
     * Toggle state and of the expander.
     *
     * @param event The click event
     * @param expanderNode
     * @param bodyId
     */
    function toggleExpander(expanderNode, bodyId, from_history) {
        var bodyNode = expanderNode.find(bodyId);
        var speed = 200; //'fast'
        if (from_history == true) {
            //No sliding time if it was remembered from history
            speed = 0;
        }
        if (expanderNode.hasClass(IS_OPEN)){
            $.each(bodyNode, function() {
                $(this).slideUp(speed, function () {
                    expanderNode.removeClass(IS_OPEN);
                    storeOrRemoveHistory(expanderNode);

                });

            });
        } else {
            $.each(bodyNode, function() {
                $(this).slideDown(speed, function () {
                    expanderNode.addClass(IS_OPEN);
                    storeOrRemoveHistory(expanderNode);
                    if ($(this).is('tr')) {
                        $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
                    }

                });

            });

        }

    }

    /**
     * Init localstorage history if localstorage available, trigger expand if any found
     * Saved by index of expanders at url.
     * @param node
     * @param titleNode
     * @param index
     */
    function initLocalStorageHistory(node, titleNode, index) {
        if(localStorageisAvailable) {
            $(node).attr('data-position', index);
            var dataPosition = window.location.href + index;

            if (localStorage.getItem(dataPosition)) {
                //Don't open anything if referrer is pren
                if($.urlParam('ref') != 'pren') {
                    $(titleNode).trigger('click', true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results != null) {
            return results[1] || 0;
        } else return null;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Save state of expander to localstorage if available
     * @param expanderNode
     */
    function storeOrRemoveHistory(expanderNode) {
        if(localStorageisAvailable){
            var dataPosition = window.location.href + $(expanderNode).attr('data-position');

            if ($(expanderNode).hasClass(IS_OPEN)) {
                localStorage.setItem(dataPosition, 'open');
            } else {
                localStorage.removeItem(dataPosition);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Enable all expanders.
     */
    $.each($('.expander'), function (i, node) {
        var titleNode = $(node).find('.expander-title:first');
        $(titleNode).append(expandButton());
        $(titleNode).click(function (event, from_history) {
            var clickTarget = $(event.currentTarget),
                expanderNode = clickTarget.closest('.expander'),
                from_history = from_history || false;
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("survey") > -1) {
                toggleExpander(expanderNode, '.expander-body', from_history);
            }
            else {
                toggleExpander(expanderNode, '.expander-body:first', from_history);
            }
        });
        initLocalStorageHistory(node, titleNode, i);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    initExpanders();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a generic catch

```
catch(e)
```

If you make a spelling mistake, this will catch `no method exception` and always return false, very nasty and hidden bug. I suggest specifying exactly the expected exception.